# How can I select/use a specific DB to alter multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I'm using SQL Server 2012 under SQL Management studio.

What I'm trying to do is run a single SQL Script that will alter multiple tables under a specific DB and add/remove columns from those tables. But I want to be able to declare and set the DB so that I can run the script from anywhere.

Right now my script looks like so....

```
---Add New Columns to Table 1 on Source DB
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1] 
ADD Test1 int, Test2 bit, Test3 varchar(255)

---Add New Columns to Table 2 on Source DB
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table2]
ADD Test4 bit, Test5 varchar(255)
```

When I run this, I have to go to the drop down menu in Management Studio, select the DB and then run it. But I want to be able to declare and set the DB in the script itself so that I dont have to select anything from the drop down menu and just run it from wherever I'm at.

Make sense? If not, Ill try and clear it up. Any help, thanks!

Comment: put USE MyDatabase at the top?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks to you too. I'm new to SQL and didnt know about "use"

Comment: you're welcome, accept Chavi's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `USE` keyword can be used to select a database you want your script to execute on.
For Eg :

```
USE {YourDBName}

---Add New Columns to Table 1 on Source DB

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1] 
    ADD Test1 int, Test2 bit, Test3 varchar(255)

---Add New Columns to Table 2 on Source DB

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table2]
    ADD Test4 bit, Test5 varchar(255)
```

Comment: That was so simple, I'm a bit embarrassed. New to SQL. Trying to learn. Thanks Chavi!

Comment: [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).